# How to determine the appropriate VSS hotfixes/updates to apply to a Windows 2003 server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-update, vss

Yes...I know...Windows 2003 has already EOL'd now.

I'm dealing with a remaining one in a large environment and have some issues that I believe are related to VSS according to a KB hotfix article.  Instead of applying just that single hotfix, I'd like to gather the VSS rollups that have been missed over the years.

For some reason I can't seem to remember or find how to check which VSS updates/hotfixes the server would need.  I know hotfixes typically are "deploy if needed in a certain situation" but Microsoft offers some VSS update rollups that include hotfixes.  However, MS is also bad about not simply publishing a chronological list that would say "here's the latest VSS rollup, apply this one".

Is there a way to find out which VSS rollups are needing to be applied to a server without trying to check file versions against each KB article?  Windows Update itself doesn't seem to list out any VSS specific patches, likely because they are considered hotfixes/hotfix rollups.

Comment: I would presume this is the latest rollup to apply: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/940349 - but I'm not certain on that...so hence the question.

Comment: Did you run across this article: http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2009/10/12/list-of-storage-related-hotfixes-post-service-pack-2-for-windows-server-2003.aspx

Comment: @austinian - no but that does help at least shortcut me to where I can figure it out manually for the most part.

Comment: I just checked to see if the VSS related hotfixes were available via the Microsoft Update catalog, and they don't seem to be, so I can't check their status with WSUS. I found http://serverfault.com/questions/15122/how-do-you-know-when-a-microsoft-hotfix-has-been-obsoleted-by-a-newer-patch and http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=223079 as related questions. Unfortunately, none of them are resolved.

Comment: @austinian - correct, WSUS wouldn't assist me on it either.  Thanks for the help...this pushes me down the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a good method for doing this if you don't have access to the  [Microsoft Premier Support](https://premier.microsoft.com) knowledgebase, which, from what I can tell [from here](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=223079), isn't even *guaranteed* to have the information you're looking for, but is simply *likely* to have it. Both I and many others seem to have searched for a tool or solution to the hotfix problem, but have found the quick-and-easy solution to be non-existent.

So, no, there still isn't an easy way to tell if a Hotfix has been superseded unless it's been clearly published as being superseded in its KB article. You're left doing the footwork (file version numbers) unless you have a support contract that will provide the information for you.

Related: [How do you know when a Microsoft hotfix has been obsoleted by a newer patch?](https://serverfault.com/questions/15122/how-do-you-know-when-a-microsoft-hotfix-has-been-obsoleted-by-a-newer-patch)

Comment: Correct that the Premier site (which I do have access to) doesn't list it, at least not in KB 940349 at https://premier.microsoft.com/kb/940349.  It does say which KB's it replaces, but doesn't say it was superceded by anything, so maybe that means it is the latest...hard to say for certain.  But I do have Premier support so I'll open a case and see what they say is the latest and report back to you and accept your answer.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: No...not really.  I opened the case and they said basically what we already discussed here.  So I ended up replacing the server with a 2012 VM  :)